# Column Space and Null Space of a Matrix

Tags: fonts, matrices, best-practices

What are the notational best-practices for typesetting the column space and null space of a matrix A?

Let's see how some of the different options look:

**Column Space**:

```
$col(\mathbf(A))$

$\mathrm{col}(\mathbf{A})$

$C(\mathbf{A})$

$\mathcal{C}(\mathbf{A})$
```

**Null Space**:

```
$null(\mathbf(A))$

$\mathrm{null}(\mathbf{A})$

$N(\mathbf{A})$

$\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A})$
```

Let me know if you have other ideas. Please let me know what you think is standard, but more importantly what you think is *best*.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some way to force LaTeX output to display here? This is strange...

Comment: This question may be off-topic for this site since it solicits opinions. You may want to pose this question in Math.SE instead.

Comment: See [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272/5764)

Comment: Anything other than *domain-codomain* pair is OK as long as you make it readable (for my taste).

Comment: Hi there -- how would you recommend I rework my question? Still wondering what notational best-practices are for typesetting null space and column space.

Comment: I don't think you should rework your question here. Rather, you should ask it in the appropriate place (e.g. Maths SE). If your question was 'Here is how I want things to look. How can I get LaTeX to produce that output?' it would be on-topic. But the question of how it *should* look is not the kind of question this site deals with. At least, it isn't concerned with questions where this is the sole or primary focus.